# Checking unique name and ignoring in case of modify

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form, a modal form which I am using to modify name/email address of the user. The problem is its sending the request to server to check unique value in all cases, its fine when creating new record but in case I am modifying something I want to ignore the current value.
here is the html code of popup

```
<form>
   <input type="text" ng-model="username" unique-url="/test/to/unique" />
</form>
```

This modal form is loaded by changing the model value, like this

```
$scope.showModal = function(row) {
    $scope.username = row.name;
    showTheFormModal();
}
```

here is the directive

```
myAPP.directive('uniqueUrl', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, ele, attrs, c) {

            var url = attrs.uniqueNameUrl + '?';

            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {

                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: url + $.param({'name': ele.val()})
                }).success(function(isUnique,status,headers,cfg) {
                        var iu = isUnique == 'true' ? true : false;
                        c.$setValidity('unique', iu);
                    }).error(function(data,status,headers,cfg) {
                        c.$setValidity('unique', false);
                    });
            });
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: Maybe it makes sense to fix it on the server better?

Comment: I can fix the server, but as ng-model value is changing based on different row so not sure how to track original value every time I open the popup

Answer (score 0):

How about doing the uniqueness check on the server instead of the client. Pass the database id back from the server and store it along with username and password. Client can then check value of id and send it with future requests. Then have an additional $http put route. Use $http put for editing existing database entries.

```
$http.put('/route/' + id, UpdatedData)

$http.get('/route/')
```